# NVARCHAR to VARCHAR2 insert

Tags: sql, oracle, nvarchar, varchar2

I have the following table structure:

```
UDA_ID (NUMBER)
Translation (NVARCHAR2)
```

I need to insert in the table

```
UDA_ID (NUMBER)
Translation (VARCHAR2)
```

How do i convert NVARCHAR2 to VARCHAR2 ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
insert into mytable(Translation)
(select to_char(Translation) from sometable);
```

or like

```
insert into mytable(Translation)
(select to_char('yourValue') from dual);
```

Comment: when I do a query
Select to_char(Translation) from mytable;

it gives invalid identifier.

Comment: @ImranHemani:- Can you create a http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4 Also it looks like you are using some incorrect names. Please check that